# Symfony ManyToMany in Form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have entity developer and entity skill, skill have ManyToMany with Platforms, Language and Speciality and I need create form for developer, developer can selected skills and when selected some skill developer can selected Platforms, Language and Speciality for this skill. If developer selected two skill or more so have more Platforms, Language and Speciality for selected. And I don't know how this is create in Symfony. Now I create form only selected skills

```
 class DeveloperProfessionalSkillsType extends AbstractType
 {
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
          ->add('name');
                     $builder->add('skills','entity',
                            array(
                                'class'=>'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill',
                                'property'=>'skill',
                                'multiple'=>true,
                            )
                        );
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer',
        'validation_groups' => array('professional_skills')
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'developer_professional_skills';
}
```

but now I have error form is not valid, interesting when I add  'expanded' => true, all work fine, but I don't need expanded I need simple selected field:
this is my entity

```
class Skill
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill", mappedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $developers;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $language;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryPlatforms
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryPlatforms", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $platforms;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectorySpecialities
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectorySpecialities", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $specialities;
```

and my action

```
    public function submitProfessionalSkillsAction($securitytoken)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new DeveloperProfessionalSkillsType(), $user->getDeveloper());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();
```

Recommend, please, how best to solve this problem

Comment: I'm sorry, but i dont understand your question...

Comment: How to add skills to developer with specialities platforms and languagies?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  $builder->add('skills','entity',
                          array( 
                                'class'=>'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill',
                                'property'=>'skill',
                                'multiple'=>true,
                            )
                        );
```

You can create new form and add it to your current form like this:

```
      $builder->add('skills', new SkillsType()
           );
```

And in new form you can define all your fields like:

```
$builder->add('language','entity',
                        array(
                            'class'=>'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Language',
                            'property'=>'some_property',
                            'multiple'=>true,
                        )
                    );
```

if you need many skills you can use collection form type:

```
    ->add('skills', 'collection', array('type' => new SkillsType(), 
    'allow_add' => true,'by_reference' => false))
```